# powershell function for convert to number

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

Im using powershell to open two excel workbook and copy data from one into another, the data I'm importing contains both text and numeric data.  After it's been imported, everything is treated as text. 
i have two columns: A and B
A has the following: 01234567 should get converted into 1234567
B has the following: 01234567.05 should get converted into 1234567.05

Of course I could manually do the "Convert to Number" function, but this import is done automatically so no manual action need to be performed. (another way to do it manually is to use the Text-to-column)

This is not working, not even manually, if i try to make the conversion using the formating function, its not doing anything
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A5000").NumberFormat = "0000000"

Comment: i have more then 5000 rows, i was hoping i could apply a function like: Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A5000").ConvertToNumber

Answer (score 1):

```
$csvData = @"
A,B
01234567, 01234567.05
-123, 00045.06
"@

# Or Import-Csv <yourpath> -delimiter <yourdelimiter> in your case
$csv = ConvertFrom-Csv $csvData -delimiter ','

Write-Host ""
Write-Host "Before conversion"
$csv

Write-Host ""
Write-Host "After conversion"


# Or Import-Csv <yourpath> -delimiter <yourdelimiter> | %{ etc... in your case
$csv = ConvertFrom-Csv $csvData -Delimiter ',' | %{
 new-object PSObject -prop @{
    A = [int] ($_.A);
    B = [double] ($_.B);
  }
}

$csv
```

Answer (score 0):

In Powershell there are several ways to do conversions to an integer. (Powershell does not have a data type number)

```
$myInt = [int]"4527427"
$myInt = [int]::Parse("4527427")    
$myInt = [System.Convert]::ToInt32("4527427")
```